# preventing duplicate table inserts using jdo in android connected appengine

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I would like to know how to prevent duplicate inserts when doing an RPC call from an Android client connected to app engine. Below is my code and what I tried at the back-end but when I do this I get an "Internal Server Error".

```
public void createentity(userentity e) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    //to go through the records and and check for duplicates
    Query q = pm.newQuery("select from" + userentity.class + "where Country=='" + e.getCCNumber() + "'");
    List < userentity > s = (List < userentity > ) q.execute();
    //if the size is equal to to null means there is no duplicate
    if (s.size() == 0) {
        //insert the value
        try {
            pm.makePersistent(e);
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SachinD When you edit a post, make sure that you fix the whole post, including code formatting ( http://jsbeautifier.com can be used in many cases), removal of greetings/signatures, and removal of chatty words.

Comment: When you reply to another comment, reply to the correct name ;) In this case, use `@Rob` or `@RobW`. For details, see [Meta: How do comment replies work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). *I replied to the previous editor of your post, to teach him how to edit.*

Comment: Thank you for guiding me.I will Remember that.Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of potential issues I see. First you should also be checking that your list isn't null. If it's null, your attempt to access the size will result in a null pointer exception. Secondly, in your query string remove the double equals. You only need single equals there. And secondly, add a spaces at the end and beginnings of your string literals. You're creating an invalid string. For instance, "select from ". And lastly, you shouldn't need to wrap the e.getCCNumber() in string literals.

```
Query q = pm.newQuery("select from " + userentity.class + " where Country= " + e.getCCNumber());
```